# How to display edges in a 3D file on Facebook

Tags: 3d, sketchup

I'm trying to show a 3D model on Facebook and display its edges and lines.
I found that I could export a 3D model from Sketchup using glTF Export plugin to a glb file that I can drag and drop in a Facebook post.

I tried many ways to set material, width, styles on lines in my model but once imported in Facebook the lines don't appear. It's not a Facebook problem since the gtTF viewer has the same display.

- Is there a missing implementation in glTF format?
- Is there another freeware to export a 3D model to Facebook (showing edges)?

**EDIT**

- Are there other formats supported by Facebook to support the line rendering?

[image]

Comment: Gltf does not support the lines just geometry. In general the lines are post process/custom rendering effects and no engine has  handlers for them.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not about graphic design but rather 3D graphics formats and what they support.

Comment: @joojaa I feel that design is indissociable from rendering. But would you recommend a more adapted community?

Comment: Perhaps, but this isnt graphic design. Not all design is graphic design, when i design electrical circuits or machinery i dont qualify. There is no generic 3D forum. You may try computer graphics but they will probably just close it. Exportting 3D assets could be asked generally though. But thts easy enoug explained in one sentence. Essentially polygons export, textures and texture cords export anything beyond that is a hit and miss.

Comment: @joojaa - I’m not actually quibbling: I’ve a question for clarification: if generic 3D questions (non blender) which are explicitly about the graphic representation achievable in a specific but generally available public forum are so non germane to GDSE that the question should be closed immediately, why then do we have tags supporting 3D topics, including some specific 3D DCC tools by published name? Further, does this suggest a need for a generic Non-Blender 3D topic area for such topics?

Comment: @GerardFalla its possible to ask genuine graphic design questions concerning 3D applications although i have only seen it done only once. But essentially asking how the fileformats of 3D work is a bit outlier. Its like asking how to program javascript. Anyway the users here can not support 3D questions very well. For every basic question of 2D design theres 100 for 3D. Generic 3D graphics site has been suggested 2 times but it always failed spectacularily. There are lots of 3D askers  but few who can answer. By isolating by program you are much more likely to get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The glTF format technically allows lines, but (1) has no mechanism for setting their width, and (2) graphics engines often have to construct a traditional mesh to display wide lines anyway. It is very likely that Facebook's viewer just ignores lines.

For best results, construct a mesh (e.g. thin elongated cubes) instead of using lines directly.

Comment: I could add mesh to simulate the lines but it wouldn't render like my first image since it won't have a fixed width to look like a pen stroke.

Comment: Not saying it will look the same, but nevertheless... you can’t export it to Facebook without using a mesh. A pen stroke-like texture might also be a good (but still different) approximation.